# Activate PHP commands on login

Tags: shell, php

Everytime I login into my centOS box.  I need to run `source /opt/rh/php54/enable` to be able to run php commands.  What do I need to do to my installation for this to work without running this command?

Comment: Did you installed php using yum/rpm? Or compiled from sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will depend on what the command is doing. However, you could automate it by adding this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
source /opt/rh/php54/enable
```

That will run the `source` command each time you log in. There is probably a better way of doing this, presumably the `enable` script is just setting some variables that you could set directly but this should work as a workaround.